# What is this index all about?

Tags: taxes, india, banking, budget, nse-india

[image]

Why did this index touch so high when our finance minister annouce the privatisation of 2 PSBs and one insurance bank?A detailed answer to this will be most welcome. She did not name any but why would that impact this index.And what is this index all about?

Comment: Nobody knows what moves the stock market.

Comment: LOL :-)However can anyone use a analogy between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes privatization signals an attitude of less regulation going forward by governments, which is always welcome news to everyone in the affected sector.  Allowing companies to be privatized opens investment in them, and they can focus on more profitable, efficient operational models and lines of business.

Any company run by bureaucrats is almost automatically far less efficient than its private-sector counterparts because those in charge have little reason to be motivated to do better.  They are caretakers drawing government salaries regardless of the failure or fortune of the companies they are in charge of.

The spike in the index is most likely a speculative one as people try to figure out what happens next and many of them are making bets about a positive future, not wanting to be left out.  So they buy stocks sector-wide, thus pushing up the related index.